# LINQ syntax question

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

I have this original SQL that I need to rewrite in LINQ :

```
SELECT 
    luProfiles.luProfileID,
    luProfiles.ProfileName,
    NoOfRights = (SELECT Count(pkProfileRightsID) FROM tblProfileRights WHERE fkProfileID = luProfileID)
FROM  luProfiles 
WHERE luProfiles.ProfileName LIKE ...
```

I have done most of it in LINQ, but I am not sure how to add the NoOfRights part to my LINQ.  This is what I have done so far :

```
return from p in _database.LuProfiles
       where p.ProfileName.ToLower().StartsWith(strProfile.ToLower())             
       select p;
```

Can anybody tell me the right syntax to include the NoOfRights part in my LINQ?

Comment: imho you are not going to get an exact mapping here, but you may get something close with a join and a group by

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from p in _database.LuProfiles
let NoOfRights = (from r in database.tblProfileRights 
                  where r.fkProfileID == p.luProfileID
                  select r).Count()
where p.ProfileName.ToLower().StartsWith(strProfile.ToLower())             
select new
{
    p.luProfileID,
    p.ProfileName,
    NoOfRights 
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply...the syntax seems to be wrong, I get the error 'The type of the expression in the select clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Select'

Comment: @user517406: Thanks. That's fixed now

Answer (score 2):

If you are using LINQ-to-SQL or EF, and you have an FK set up, you should have a navigational property `ProfileRights`. Tn that case, you can query this way:

```
from p in _database.LuProfiles
where p.ProfileName.ToLower().StartsWith(strProfile.ToLower())
select new 
{
    p.ProfileId,
    p.ProfileName,
    NoOfRights = p.ProfileRights.Count()
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this would help you out:

```
from l in luProfiles
where l.ProfileName.Contains(something)
select new
{
    l.luProfileID,
    l.ProfileName,
    noOfRights = tblProfileRights.Count(t => t.fkProfileID == l.luProfileID)
}
```

Comment: Probably you need to `select new { }`

Comment: @abatishchev: Yeah, totally forgot about that at first. Edited after I actually saw what I wrote down.

Comment: btw, not sure that `IEnumerable<T>.Count(Predicate<T>)` will be mapped to SQL correctly.

Comment: @abatishchev: Since I don't really have a database handy to check it out, I'm not really sure, but I think it should work. Have you had any problems with such an approach?

Comment: Alex, i'm have no too, but just sometimes ran into the situation when something looking in "just LINQ" was not working in LINQ to SQL/E

Comment: @abatishchev: LINQ to SQL is much more lenient than LINQ to EF. Maybe you had problems with EF (as have I).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to change SQL first to something like this:

```
SELECT 
  luProfiles.luProfileID,
  luProfiles.ProfileName,
  NoOfRights = COUNT(pkProfileRightsID)
FROM luProfiles
LEFT JOIN tblProfileRights ON fkProfileID = luProfileID
WHERE luProfiles.ProfileName like ...
GROUP BY luProfiles.luProfileID, luProfiles.ProfileName
```

So this can easily be transformed to LINQ:

```
return from p in _database.LuProfiles
join o in p.Profiles on p.luProfileID equals o.fkProfileID
group p by new { p.luProfileID, p.ProfileName } into g
select new { g.Key.luProfileID, g.Key.ProfileName , g.Count() }
```

(not tested, so do it yourself)